# How can I get access to PHP_AUTH_* variables in a custom component in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, authentication

Very simple test case:

Copy lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/BasicAuthenticate.php to myapp/Controller/Component/Auth/MyAppAuthAuthenticate.php

Put it in my Controller/AppController.php's beforeFilter()

this->Auth->authenticate = array(

```
              'MyAppAuth' => array(

                  'fields' => array('username' => 'email')

              ),
```

Great. Everything works so far (tracing them in the debug logs shows that they are being called correctly.) However, when I log these:

$username = env('PHP_AUTH_USER');
$pass = env('PHP_AUTH_PW');

They are empty. In the original BasicAuthenticate.php, they are populated. Is there something special needed to be able to see these env vars in a custom component? The rest of the env vars (like SERVER_NAME, etc.) are all present.

Answer (score 0):

With no changes whatsoever, it started working.